# Get combobox values from access

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a `winform` project with an `access file` as a `database`.
In one of my forms I want the user to choose a `company` from a `combobox`.

**(the list of campanies is in the access table)**

How do I set the `company name` column to be combobox dropdown values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string qr1 = "select companyname from table1";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qr1, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        cmbcat.Items.Clear();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            cmbcat.Items.Add(dr1[0].ToString());

        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: how many items can you add to such a combobox? I guess there are some limits.

Comment: I know con meens connection, if I;m using an oleDbCommand, will I be able to do it your way?

Answer (score -1):

to Nimi

is this oledbcommand?

my solutions is ....

```
public void make_cbDispatch()           
{     
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
                                    + "Data Source=I:\\Projects\\project.accdb;"
                                    + "Persist Security Info=False;";

        string qr1 = "SELECT DISTINCT object "
                                    + "FROM tList "
                                    + "ORDER BY object ";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(qr1, con);
        con.Open();
         OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        cbDispatch.Items.Clear();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            cbDispatch.Items.Add(dr1[0].ToString());

        }
        con.Close();

}
```